# How to choose CPU for dedicated server?

Tags: hardware, dedicated-server

I know that this is a stupid question, but i don't understand what PassMark rating mean. I don't understand how to compare "5000" and "9000" of rating. I'm totally understand that everything is depends on my program code and environment, but still.

For example, let's say that i have a WordPress blog with a standart template that have 5000 of hosts per day with maximum of 200 users in peak (200000 of pageviews). Will i get any lags with next configuration (no ping)?

- Intel Xeon E3 1225v2 (6700 passmark)
- 16 GB RAM
- 300 GB SSD
- 250 Mbps

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to do some simple math: 200 users in peak. Each would read article for at least for about a minute(depends on nature and size of your articles) before clicking on some other link in your blog. So, that gives us about 200/60 request per second, that's about 3 requests per second for 4 core server. That's about 1 request per second per core. I'd say this can be easily handled by this CPU (I don't know amount of plugins and other stuff installed on your wordpress node). If for some craze reason that's not enough you can install some caching plugin/nginx/memcache/redis and it'd boost performance hundred times.